# Python https website scraping error with betting sites, using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've just started to familiarize myself with web site scraping, using Python 3.5.2 with the latest Requests and BeautifulSoup modules. Yesterday I ran into the following problem:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.betfair.com/exchange/', verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title)
```

The previous code worked great for every http and https website, except betfair.com and all of its subdomain. (I'm aware that Betfair has an API)
I also installed requests[security] using pip, but it didn't help.
Any help is highly appreciated! My error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 417, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1426, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1174, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'unknown protocol')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 835, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 323, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 324, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 424, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'unknown protocol')],)",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 624, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'unknown protocol')],)",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Betfair Goal Bot/teszt.py", line 5, in <module>
    page = requests.get('https://www.betfair.com/exchange/', verify=False)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Balazs91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'unknown protocol')],)",)
```

Comment: I don't seem to be getting the same error (then again I am using python 2.7 so it's not quite the same). I know that there are some github forums that deal with this issue. You might also want to check out: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings I know its not much to go on but maybe it will lead you in the right direction

Comment: The code works fine. I think the problem is your network.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, it turned out that my country blocked many online sport betting sites, including Betfair. The same code works great now with a VPN.

Comment: @BalázsMagyar: good for diagnosing your own problem. Please write and accept that one-line answer so this question can be closed. (There are many other questions on certificate errors with BS, for various reasons)